# Magento 2 : Cannot set product stock status to "Out of stock" using csv

Tags: magento2, product, import, csv, inventory

I tried to **import** a **product** using **CSV** with **is_in_stock** value to **'0'** and after the import, the stock status still shows "**In stock**"

CSV looks like this :

> sku,is_in_stock
>
> DC3508BR,0

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: It may be due to Magento bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9774

Comment: Try using the string "Out of stock" instead of `0`.

Comment: Make column name as "qty" and add 0 into it for products which you want to put in as out of stock

Answer (score 0):

In order to update stock in Magento 2 using csv, for most scenarios, you will only need to include '**sku**' and '**qty**' columns.

However, I am assuming for the products in question you already have stock management turned on either globally or per product and you are not using 'backorders'. For more details on advanced stock management see the Magento documentation: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-product-stock-options.html

`is_in_stock` (which maps to 'Stock Availability') is not required either as in most scenarios (based on assumptions above) Magento will auto set this based on whether you provide a stock qty of above 0 or not (i.e. qty of **0** or less will set **Out of Stock**, **1** or above will set '**In Stock**')

So, in your case you just need to define '**sku**' and '**qty**'. **Stock Availability** will be auto selected based on QTY.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working code sample, we use it in a custom console command. Here we use **\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository** as **$productRepository** & **\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface** as **$stockRegistry**

In this code, we set **$isInStock** value dynamically, based in **$qty** value

```
try {
    $product = $productRepository->get($sku);
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
    $output->writeln('<info>Could not load!<info>');
    continue;
}

$stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem(
    $product->getId(),
    $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
);

$stockItem->setData('qty',$qty);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock',$isInStock);
$stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
```